# Storyboard UiView set size with code?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have `UIViewA` by Storyboard with `(w,h,x,y)`

I want to change size `UIViewA` by code

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBOutlet for that UIView object in you ViewController class and set its frame in ViewDidload or wherever you want to set the frame programmatically.
Note: I assume you are not using auto-layout.

Comment: i used to auto-layout

Answer (score 0):

[UIViewA setFrame:yourFrameWithChangedSize];

Comment: if You're using auto layout, create outlets for constraints of width / heights and change their constant values

Answer (score 0):

try like this 
add this **.h**

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *yourview;
```

in **.m** file

```
@synthesize yourview
```

**create your view where you want**

```
`yourview.frame = CGRectMake(10,100,300,40)`;

  self.view = yourview;
```

**change your view  where u need**

```
yourview.frame = CGRectMake(102,200,300,40);
```

please refer this [link](http://matthewmorey.com/creating-uiviews-programmatically-with-auto-layout/)

Comment: i used to autolayout then don't use yourview.frame = CGRectMake(10,100,300,40);

  [self.view addSubview:yourview];